# how can i get total_pages from themoviesdb-api and save it to a variable?

Tags: arrays, async-await, get, themoviedb-api

i have the following function:

```
const getTotalPages = async () => {
  const selectedGenre = getSelectedGenre();
  const discoverMovieEndpoint = '/discover/movie';
  const requestParams =`api_key=${tmdbKey}&with_genres=${selectedGenre}&total_pages=True`;
  const urlToFetch = `${tmdbBaseUrl}${discoverMovieEndpoint}${requestParams}`;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(urlToFetch);
    if (response.ok) {
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      const totalPages = jsonResponse.total_pages; 
      return totalPages;
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
     console.log(error);
  }
 }
```

and then i want to use it inside another function like that:

```
const getMovies = async () => {
  const selectedGenre = getSelectedGenre();
  const discoverMovieEndpoint = '/discover/movie';
  const requestParams = `?api_key=${tmdbKey}&with_genres=${selectedGenre}&page=${Math.ceil(Math.random()*getTotalPages())}`;
  const urlToFetch = `${tmdbBaseUrl}${discoverMovieEndpoint}${requestParams}`;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(urlToFetch);
    if (response.ok) {
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      const movies = jsonResponse.results; 
      return movies;
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

so I can i display a random result from a **random page, not just from the first page** but I'm getting undefined. By the way, `getSelectedGenre()` works fine. I've searched here and in tmdb discourse page and found that others before me struggled with similar issue but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Have you tried to `await getTotalPages()` in `getMovies` ?

Comment: i have either by  putting all the logic of `getTotalPages()` inside a nested `await fetch()` statement, or just now after your suggestion, assigning `await  getTotalPages()` to a variable and using that variable in new `requestParams`. Same, undefined.

Comment: Do you need to `await getSelectedGenre()` as well ?

Comment: no , it's a simple helper function that gets the value from a document  element. The whole `getMovies()` listed above works fine (with `getSelectedGenre()` if i remove `&page` parameter from the request. It returns array of movies from the first page of movies of a particular genre. But there are multiple pages, i could access specific page, but i want to be able for my app to suggest a random movie from **all** pages, so i believe first i need to get a random page and then a random movie from a page.